# Image is not Show in React js . Whe I want to show image it's not showing . without This Every Thing is Okay

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

> I want to import image from other component but Why it's not show. in
> Data.js I'm showing the image path. but when I want it . it's not show
> in HOME. but Without Image Everything is work properly

**Data.js**

```
export const HomeObject = {
    id: 'about', 
    img: require('../../Images/sv-1.svg'),
    alt:'CAR',
}
```

**Home.jsx**

```
const Info = ({img, alt}) => {
    return (

          <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
)
```

Comment: By the way . I was Import Other Important Thing also

Answer (score 1):

React `img` works similar to html `img` tag. pass file path as src value to show the image.

when passing image src as prop to the component, keep in mind that it needs to be a string value. not `require('...')` value.

```
const Parent = () => {
  return (<Info img={'../../Images/sv-1.svg'} alt={'info image'}>
};

const Info = ({img, alt}) => {
    return (
          <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
    );
}
```

this works fine in local setup. but, when you deploy the application, serve the image as static resource and use it.

Comment: I want to some dynamic img . and The img filed like a tamplate

Comment: id: 'discover',
    lightbg: true,
    lightText:false,
    lightTextDesc:false,
    topLine:' The Captaion ',
    headLine: ' The Poor Guy is Now A KING ',
    imgStart:true,
    img: require('../../Images/02.svg'),
    alt:'CAR',
    buttonLabel:"What Next",
    dark:true,
    primary:true,
    darktext:true

Comment: Like This is a Post Tamplate and the image is I can reuse again again with the path will be change

Comment: if by dynamic you mean image needs to be loaded when this component renders, this does exactly that. images are fetched from `src` string when need to be shown.